# Why were Arians outnumbered on the First Council of Nicaea?

Tags: religion, ancient-rome, christianity

Constantine was baptized by an [Arian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arianism) bishop a few years after the Council of Nicaea. His sons were Arians. At least the leadership of the Visigoths that sacked Rome where Arians. That was in 410, only 85 years after Nicea (325).

Yet there were only 2 Arians of 300 Bishops in the Council of Nicea that was convinced enough of Arianism to refuse to sign the [Nicene creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed).

So why were there so few Arians on the First Council of Nicaea?

In quora people said that the majority of "Arians" were in the west of the empire and hence too far from Nicea. So very few of Arians were in Nicea. Another theory is that Arians were a new idea. I want to know which one is true.

Here are similar questions in quora:

[Why were Arians underrepresented at the First Council of Nicaea?](http://www.quora.com/Why-were-Arians-underrepresented-at-the-First-Council-of-Nicaea)

[How was the representation of bishops at the Council of Nicea determined?](http://www.quora.com/How-was-the-representation-of-bishops-at-the-Council-of-Nicea-determined)

Note: I've heard a theory that most Arian supporters were in the west and Nicea is far away in the east. Also, most Christians at that time, did not consider the Trinity/homoousion a "big thing". They did not think it would concern them. I forget the source.

That is why very few western bishops came in and that explains why Arians were outnumbered. Still, I want to know more about this aspect of history.

Comment: This may get a better answer at Christianity.se

Comment: I think answers from Christianity.se would be biased in favor of trinitarians. It'll be something along, because God has decree that the right doctrines win.

Comment: I want pure secular historical answer. I can ask both.

Comment: Why is it terrible at all? In quora people said that the majority of "Arians" are in the west of the empire and hence too far from Nicea. Also the fact that the number of Arians are so large shows that it may not be a new thing.

Comment: @JimThio It's terrible because it's deeply confused. You seem to for example think that the sack of Rome (410) happened before the council of Nicaea (325).

Comment: Sack of Rome happened after the council of Nicea. That means within 85 years, there are enough Arians to sack Rome.

Comment: @JimThio Again confused: We don't know how many of the Visigoths that were Arians. But even so, your question should the reasonably be: How did Arianism grow so fast?

Comment: Because they may not have grown so fast. May be there were already tons of them during Nicea council. That's something I wanted to know.

Comment: @JimThio: That would require the ideas to spread **even more rapidly**, as the Council was only 12 years after Arius started the conflict. So now it must have grown from 1 person to your completely baseless estimate of 50% of all christians in 12 years. Which means your question makes even less sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10950/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-jim-thio)

Comment: Edited and added tags. I tried to remove the specious conjectures and guesstimates and to keep the good kernel of the question.

Comment: Lennart, you did make the question much better. Thank you. I can't vote up your answer till I know it's true.

Comment: I tried. Didn't get in.

Comment: A not about your updates: The second of your Quora-answers point out that western bishops were not interested in the conflict. Therefore your claim that most Arians were in the west is *contradicted* by this claim. They saw it as an eastern conflict. Arianus was in the east, this was a discussion between eastern bishops, the western bishops, according to this answer, didn't care. Hence they were not arians, hence Arians were not underrepresented. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Downvote restored, voted to close as based on false assumptions.

Comment: Where did you find it. I wanted to quote that part first. Some other page told me that different between Homoiousion and Homoousion doesn't concern the western part of the empire. Arian may not be the only one that disagree with Trinity.

Comment: *Constantine was baptized by an Arian bishop a few years after the Council of Nicaea* - We don't know for sure who exactly baptized him, nor do we know for sure the exact religion of some of those who *might* have.

Comment: *within 85 years, there are enough Arians to sack Rome* - A barbarian king formally embracing Arianism is not quite the same as the entire population being fervent Arian believers, let alone having been so for generations prior to that point in time.

Answer (score 9):

**Arians were not underrepresented at the council of Nicaea**

Arius [started saying](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf202.ii.iv.v.html) that the Son was distinct from the father under [Alexander of Alexandria](http://www.patriarchateofalexandria.com/index.php?module=content&cid=001003&id=96&lang=en), so it's probably in 313 or so. So Arianism was less than twelve years old at the Council. So the reason there were so few Arians on this council was that Arianism was a very new thing, not that they were underrepresented.

At the council of Nicaea there were a few bishops who supported Arius position ([Warren Carroll claims 22](http://books.google.pl/books?id=5nXYAAAAMAAJ&q=The%20building%20of%20Christendom%20Carroll&dq=The%20building%20of%20Christendom%20Carroll&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H4tTUpDUO8ql0QXp9oHYCA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA)). But they didn't prevail, and the two you mention are the only ones who preferred to be thrown out of the church than to sign the Nicean creed. (Source: Carroll again)

Your further comments and claims about there being many Arians are first of all not evidence that Arianism was widespread. It's just points out some notable Arians, but it says nothing about how widespread it was.

Comment: That the idea that Jesus may not be God is new. I mean obviously non christians believe that. But to have most Jesus' followers not thinking he is a God but mere prophets, for example. Is that really a new idea?

Comment: Your answer said that Arians are underrepresented in Nicea because they are new doctrines. However, there are many Arians around. Your answer is they are new but spread quickly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10949/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-jim-thio)

Comment: @user4951: This was not the Arian belief. The Arians, just like the non-Arians, were unanimous in their belief that Jesus Christ was the incarnation of God's Word, through Whom the world was created. Where they differed, however, was that the former believed Him to have been created by God from nothingness prior to Creation-proper, in the same manner in which a smith or artificer, through the aid of hammer and anvil, creates all other future tools; whereas the latter believed Him to be part of God's eternal being, i.e., *homo-ousios*.